# Can we integrate DD4T and SDL Mobile?

Tags: context-engine

In one of our projects we need to Implement SDL Mobile using DD4T.
Can we integrate DD4T with SDL Mobile?

Thanks,
Prasanna

Comment: Hi Prasanna and welcome to Tridion Stack Exchange. I think this is a good question to ask (DD4T with SDL Mobile?), but you'll likely get downvotes because it is rather high-level question that can be answered with a simple "yes" or "no." For better responses you might ask _how_ to approach this or _where_ to get more information. The community especially likes to see questions that include what you've tried, code/errors, and what you expected.

Comment: @AlvinReyes I will follow your instructions for next questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DXA (aka. [SDL Tridion Reference Implementation](https://community.sdl.com/developers/tridion_developer/m/mediagallery/852)) comes with a built in integration with SDL Mobile (see chapter [Setting up Context Engine Cartridge (SDL Mobile)](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Reference%20Implementation-v1/GUID-269E7DFA-03E6-4748-999C-424CED551BBC) in the documentation), and since it is using DD4T as a content provider, it is the closests example I can think of that would answer your question with a clear **Yes**.

Comment: We are waiting to use DXA to be more stabilized before we implement for projects, To make my application compatible with DXA planned to use DD4T, then the above question raised, you clarified my doubt. can you also suggest me whether the approach I mentioned works(DXA compatible application)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use both libraries in the same web application.

SDL Mobile capabilities are generally expressed through ADF claims so you might want to brush up on your ADF skills.

DD4T doesn't itself integrate with SDL Mobile as it is essentially an MVC model provider. Your own controllers and views will have to get the information they need from SDL Mobile.